# Loop is not working the way i intend it to

Tags: java

So, honestly this should be a very simple loop. To clarify, this is how I want it to work. I ask the user "Please enter an ISBN number to verify ". After they user inputs the number, it will ask "Would you like to enter another number? " If the user inputs "yes" then it will once again prompt the user to enter another number. "Please enter an ISBN number to verify " This continues until the user input "No". Hopefully this makes sense, this is what I have so far:

```
System.out.println("Press 1 to enter a list of ISBN numbers to verify. ");
System.out.println("Press 2 to convert an ISBN-10 number to an ISBN-13 number. ");
System.out.println("Press 3 to quit. ");
choice = input.nextInt();

if(choice == 1){

     do{
        //Get the ISBN
        System.out.println("Please Enter an ISBN number with dashes to verify. ");
        isbns.add(input.nextLine());
        //loops till answer is yes or no
        while(isbns.add(input.nextLine()))
            System.out.println("Would you like to add another ISBN?");
        ans = input.nextLine();
        if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            break;
    }while(!(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N")));
    input.close();
```

What I have right now tends to just do nothing when I enter Yes or NO.

Comment: `while (isbns.add(input.nextLine()))` seems weird to me - how would it be possible for this to ever result in `false` and there by break the loop?

Comment: I properly indented your code, which should help you figure out your own code ;) Keep your code formatted and use explicit code blocks `{ ... }`

Comment: and refactor your code, if you do not understand it anymore ;-) sometimes autoformater of IDE's are usefull

Comment: `if(ans.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))` based on the available context, seems pointless

Comment: the while(isbns.add(input.nextLine())) was intended to be that whenever I add another number to the arrayList the loop will continue. but I guess that not how you do it

Answer (score 0):

You made a very complicated solution for a very simple problem. Why not use simple while loop?

```
System.out.println("Press 1 to enter a list of ISBN numbers to verify. ");
System.out.println("Press 2 to convert an ISBN-10 number to an ISBN-13 number. ");
System.out.println("Press 3 to quit. ");
choice = input.nextInt();

//A token to keep track of user's choice to continue the program
String userChoise = "Y";

if(choice == 1){
  while(userChoise.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    //Get the ISBN
    System.out.println("Please Enter an ISBN number with dashes to verify. ");
    isbns.add(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Would you like to add another ISBN?");
    userChoise = input.nextLine();
  }
  input.close();
}
```

Comment: This asks both questions at the same time, is there a way to first ask them to enter an ISBN and once the user does that it will ask if they want to enter another?

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor edit to @Ratul Bin Tazul's answer. I do support the use of a do while loop, because it is clear from the case that at least once execution of the code inside the loop is required.

One more thing that you need to take care of is to use a nextLine() after calling nextInt(). This is because nextInt doesn't consume the '\n' at the end of the previous input, and this is why you were getting both your lines printed at the same time.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Press 1 to enter a list of ISBN numbers to verify. ");
System.out.println("Press 2 to convert an ISBN-10 number to an ISBN-13 number. ");
System.out.println("Press 3 to quit. ");

choice = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();

//A token to keep track of user's choice to continue the program
String userAnswer;

if(choice == 1){
  do {
    //Get the ISBN
    System.out.println("Please Enter an ISBN number with dashes to verify. ");
    isbns.add(input.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Would you like to add another ISBN?");
    userAnswer = input.nextLine();
  }while( !userAnswer.equalsIgnoreCase("N"));
  input.close();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the questions are not asked at the same time? when I use this, it asks both questions instead one then the other if that makes sense

Comment: You mean await a user's input, and then ask the next question?
Can you share how the variable 'input' was defined?

Comment: exactly! it will ask them to input the isbn number, after the user inputs the number, it will then ask the user if they would like to enter another

Comment: Fixed it in the answer now.

Comment: If it helped you, could you accept the answer please? :)